# Разные сессии в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, сессия

Всем привет, у меня есть *TodoList* в нем список дел их можно удалять добавлять и зачеркивать. Как сделать чтоб например я открыл свое приложение в двух вкладках, в первой я удалил одно дело, и в другой вкладке оно так же удалилось, как можно реализовать данный функционал, может с помощью *redux*.

Comment: Где хранится сам список todo? Что из себя представляет бэк и как организовано общение клиента с бэком?

Comment: речь только про вкладки одного браузера?

Comment: Бэка нету, только фронт, речь идёт только про вкладки одного браузера. Я написал проект просто для изучения redux, у меня просто сейчас есть задача, что нужно написать локальный чат , в котором залогиниться войти в чат и что-то написать, а потом открыть другую вкладку и сделать так же. И чтоб был общий чат одной комнаты например, и напримере Todo list , хочу понять как сделать общий store грубо говоря и в одной вкладки изменил и в другой отобразилось.

Comment: Даже запуская одно приложение в разных вкладках, это приложение работать САМО ПО СЕБЕ не зная о существовании другого. Без бэковой части, которая бы связывала хоть как то инстрансы приложения не обойтись. Можно конечно попробовать сделать это на localStorage. redux будет генерить хранилище для каждого инстанса приложения свой, так что это не вариант.

Comment: тогда используй localStorage, и событие [`storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) для обновления своих данных